# Loops and "i" - Correctly inputting "i"

Tags: vba, loops

I have no idea how to add in the "i" to the following code.  I've gone through previous questions, but I can't get this to run properly.  Ideas?  Starting after "ELSE", I have no idea how to add in the "i".  Any help would be appreciated.

```
For i = 2 To myLastRow

Set mycell = myWorksheet.Range("AK" & i)
Set mycell2 = myWorksheet.Range("AD" & i)

Else
    **mycell.Offset(, 2).Formula = "==IF(ABS(AJ" & i & " - AL" & i & ") <= AL" & i & "*0.1, TRUE, FALSE) "**
```

Comment: What do you expect adding the `i` to do? You need to know why you're adding something before you're going to understand how to do it correctly.

Comment: The code I have inputs the same exact formula into each cell... the formula to go by row.  For example:  

=if(A2=B2,TRUE, FALSE)
=IF(A3=B3,TRUE, FALSE)
=IF(A4=B4,TRUE,FALSE)

At this point... it inputs the formula (i.e. =IF(A2=B2,TRUE,FALSE) into every single cell rather than the row determining the cell value.

Comment: You have 2 equal signs in your formula property.

Comment: Consider adding some tags to indicate what language you're working in.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim mylastrow As Integer
Dim myworksheet As Worksheet
Dim mycell As Range
Dim mycell2 As Range

Set myworksheet = Sheet1
mylastrow = 10

For i = 2 To mylastrow
    Cells(i, "AK").Offset(, 2).Formula = "=IF(ABS(AJ" & i & " - AL" & i & ") <= AL" & i & "*0.1, TRUE, FALSE) "
 '   Cells(i, "AD").Value
Next i
```

Are you trying to do something like this? The cells property works perfect for thse types of loops.